# Kendo Ui ASP Grid slow on rendering

Tags: javascript, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo Ui Grid with three column where the first column is a check box, and the other 2 contains text. The problem I am having is that the check box is rendering to slow. While the grid is render and the data is populated really fast I have to wait a few seconds for the check box to render. And whike I am waiting I can see that there are numbers in the column, before the check box are render. I was thinking of maybe converting it so that it is created using javascript code to see if it would be faster. Does anybody see anything my my code that would cause it to render slower, or performance improvements, or perhaps doing it in javascript is would be much faster.

```
<td id="typeGrid">
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.TypeList)
 .Name("TypeList")
 .Columns(columns =>
 {
   columns.Bound("myID").Sortable(false).Width("35px")
     .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox'  name='typeId' value=#=myID#>")
     .Title("<input type='checkbox' onclick='checkAll(event)'>");
   columns.Bound("Name").Title("Name");
   columns.Bound("Type").Title("Type");
   })             
 .Sortable()                                                            
 .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
 .Selectable(select => select.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
 .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Ajax()
      .ServerOperation(false)
      )
  )
 </td>
```

**EDIT**

Upon closer in inspection I notice that the input check box from the template is not render until my drop box is render. Could the drop box rendering slowly causes the template to not be apply until the drop box is render? They both use the same object.

```
<td id="PermType" style="vertical-align: top;">
  @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("theTypeList") 
    .DataTextField("Type Name") 
    .DataValueField("myTypeID")    
    .BindTo(Model.myTypeList)                                 )
</td>

// the code above for the grid goes after this
```

My model

```
 public class myModel
{      
    public List<subType> TypeList { get; set; }
    public List<mainType> myTypeList { get; set; }

    public class subType
    {
        public int myID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }          
        public string Type { get; set; }
         public int mainTypeID { get; set; }

    }

    public class mainType
    {           
        public string myTypeID { get; set; }  
        //other property

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `DataSource` you're setting `Ajax` for the "method" but you're passing in an object to the `Grid`.  I think that could cause a problem.

**Edit from comments**

Try changing your data source to this (I think the syntax may be a little off, but intellisense should be able to help):

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.TypeList)
 .Name("TypeList")
 .Columns(columns =>
 {
   columns.Bound(x => x.myID).Sortable(false).Width("35px")
     .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox'  name='typeId' value='#=myID#'>")
     .Title("<input type='checkbox' onclick='checkAll(event)'>");
   columns.Bound(x => x.Name).Title("Name");
   columns.Bound(x => x.Type).Title("Type");
   })             
 .Sortable()                                                            
 .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
 .Selectable(select => select.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
 .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Model(mdl => mdl.Id(x => x.myID))
  )
```

I suspect it's because of the `Selectable()` which I've never used.

Comment: I tried changing it to `Server()` and also tried removing the `DataSource` completely and is getting the error `There is no DataSource Model Id property specified.`

Comment: Sorry I should clarify, the model Id the error is referring to is not the id in my model, the Id in my model is called something else, I just changed it here for security reason. I fixed my code to better reflect this. there is no `Model` available for datasource. I also deleted `Selectable()` no work. But please look at my edit, I found something might be useful.

Comment: Can you post what your Model looks like?

Comment: I updated my code to change the bindings also.  When you say "it doesn't work" do you mean it throws an error or loads slowly still?

Comment: For deleting `selectable` it is still slow.

Comment: I change my binding and it is a bit faster now, and the first time I go to the page in Firefox/IE it works, but subsequent refresh makes it slow. For GC it always slow

Comment: Also, I added ' around `value='#=myID#'`

Comment: No there is no error, but it seems that the rendering stall while doing something on somebody else's code. Going to look into that, becuase whe I navigate to that page their piece of code does not stall, but when I refresh it does. That might be the problem.